# How to extend the Grav CMS Core

Tags: php, content-management-system, grav

Is it any way of extend the Grav CMS without the usage of plugins or modify the core/system files.

I would like to extend the following file:

```
 system/src/Grav/Common/Page/Medium/VideoMedium.php
```

If I modified this file it is going to be replaced in the next Grav update.

Maybe it is a way to extend the core files creating a similar filesystem structure inside the user directory, maybe something like:

```
user/src/Grav/Common/Page/Medium/VideoMedium.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible. You will need to create a plugin, everytime the page is initialized you add your custom Video media to it, the same way the original medium are added in system/src/Grav/Common/Page/Page.php.